# How to set up Maven in Windows?

Tags: maven

I am getting this error:

> C:\Users\roopa>mvn -version
> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I had set the environment variables as M2_HOME (Maven path), M2 (bin path). Also set the variables for JDK and JRE Path. Still the same error, maven is not recognized.

Comment: Search for "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" in Stack Overflow, and you will find that all such questions are the same - you may have an executable binary on your system, but since the system path does not include the folder in which the binary is stored, it cannot be found.

Comment: [This search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file&mixed=0) produces about 6000 results, some detailed information should be in there `:=)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the maven bin path to the Path variable at the Environment Variables also.
2. Be sure that you exit the command window and reopen after you made the changes

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you rightly configured the M2_HOME variable ? Just be sure that the M2_HOME variable is the path to the maven folder and not bin or something

Did you add the "bin" folder in the maven folder in you PATH variable ? Because in the bin folder there is the mvn.cmd which you execute while doing the "mvn" command

Did you also set the JAVA_HOME environment variable ? You need to do a
`set JAVA_HOME=Path to JDK folder` to set it.